# parsejson rendering through template in javascript

Tags: jsonp, jsrender

I have parseJson object as follows...

```
parseJSON([
{"BOOK_Name":"AAA”,"quickRead":[{"Page_Heading":"AAA-heading","Page_Url":"http://rtrt.com"},{"Page_Heading":"AAA-heading2","Page_Url":"http://bghfhghf.com"}]},
{"BOOK_Name":"BBB","quickRead":[{"Page_Heading":"BBB-heading","Page_Url":"http://dsdfdf.com"},{"Page_Heading":"BBB-heading2","Page_Url":"http://rtrtdfdf.com"}]}
]}
```

I am able to render this partially in tbody element using javascript jsrender as follows.... i.e able to render book_name but not quickread ... so how can I render data within quickread inside say

element?

```
$('tbody', '#bookTemplateTable').html($('#bookTemplate').render(data));
```

template for the same is as follows:

```
<script id="bookTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr>
      <td>{{=BOOK_Name}}</td>

      <td> 
        <ul>
          <li> .. render 1st quickread value .. </li>
          <li> .. render 1st quickread value .. </li>
        </ul> 
      </td>
    </tr>  
</script>
```

can anyone help on this?

Comment: anyone there who can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best for you to take a look at [jsrender demo](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/demos.html) page. There you can learn how to use template tags.

First, you should use

```
{{>propertyName}}
{{:propertyName}}
```

to display data. See [this demo](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/03_converters-and-encoding.html) for explanation on when to use what.

For your particular case, here is the valid template:

```
<script id="bookTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr>
      <td>{{>BOOK_Name}}</td>

      <td> 
        <ul>
          {{for quickRead}}
            <li><a href="{{>#data.Page_Url}}">{{>#data.Page_Heading}}</a></li>
          {{/for}}
        </ul> 
      </td>
    </tr>  
</script>
```

Working example can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/EGFbq/